# How can i make this content be available for "save as"?

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

this is my code from the servlet:

```
private void createLog(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=file.txt");

            String s = "Hello world";
            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF8"));

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

            while ((read = input.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                os.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }
```

and this is my ajax-call

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myServlet', 
        data: { request : "createLog" } 
    })
    .success(function(response) {
        console.log("all good");
    })
    .error(function(response){

    })
    .done(function(){

    });

});
```

so i get the content of the file, but only in the response in the browser. I want to be able to download this file, so i can save it on my computer. 
what am i missing?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may not trigger a file download through ajax.

Comment: You **cannot** trigger a file download through ajax

Comment: Okai. so how can i make this possible with without it?

Comment: Just use a link `<a href="/foo/your/file"`>your file</a>`, then make sure that the URL in the `href` is attended by the servlet that will trigger the file download.

Comment: I did. And it only takes me to that page. It will not download the content.

Comment: If you always want to trigger a file download, then use `response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");`

Comment: Alternatively, with HTML5, if you use `<a href="somefile" download>sometext</a>`, it should prompt you to download the file.